# How to automatically reduce size of outer container when using absolute positioning?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position, fluid-layout

I have a twitter bootstrap responsive layout where I would like the outer div's height to reduce automatically when the inner elements are reduced in size.  My problem is that I am using an absolute position in the child element which makes the container look empty, forcing me to set a minimum height. I do not know how to achieve the desired effect otherwise.

You can see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dansalmo/R4hPf/3/show/

I want to be able to re-size to phone width and not have the large gap between the image and nav bar as the image size is reduced.

The code is here if you want to fork it and show a possible fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/dansalmo/R4hPf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not quite understand but can want this?

http://jsfiddle.net/R4hPf/5/

Or possibly this:

http://jsfiddle.net/R4hPf/6/

I've only changed values​​:

```
.banner{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.logo{
  margin-bottom:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
.user-access {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Version 5 is exactly what I needed, thank you very much.  I noticed that you put the user-access <div> before logo <div> in addition to the value changes.